# Xen 4.0.1 not booting with device not found error

Tags: grub2, xen

I'm trying to get Xen 4.0.1 run as dom0 on a fresh/clean install of 10.10 desktop (x64).

Followed the step by step tutorial at http://wiki.xensource.com/xenwiki/Xen4.0

I have the pvops kernel in /boot, also included the ext4 fs support by recompiling the kernel by :

```
make -j6 linux-2.6-pvops-config CONFIGMODE=menuconfig
make -j6 linux-2.6-pvops-build
make -j6 linux-2.6-pvops-install
```

Here's my grub entry :

```
menuentry 'Xen4' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
        recordfail
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        insmod ext3
        set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 2bf3177a-92fd-4196-901a-da8d810b04b4
        multiboot  /xen-4.0.gz dom0_mem=1024M loglvl=all guest_loglvl=all
        module     /vmlinuz-2.6.32.27 root=UUID=2bf3177a-92fd-4196-901a-da8d810b04b4 ro
        module     /initrd.img-2.6.32.27
}
```

blkid /dev/sda1 gives the :

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="2bf3177a-92fd-4196-901a-da8d810b04b4" TYPE="ext3"
```

My partition shemes is :

```
/boot (ext3) (/dev/sda1)
/ (ext4) (/dev/sda5)
```

Whatever option i've tried i end up with :

```
mounting none on /dev failed: no such file or directory
```

And message complaining that it cannot find the device with uuid ...

Edit : 
also tried to put root=/dev/sda1 (and /dev/sda5)
also put acpi=off noapic nolapic

Always fall back to initramfs busy box. When in initramfs i try to see whether there is a /dev/sdXX and nothing, neighter /dev/device*.

my /lib/modules/2.6.32.27/ only contains a very few amount of files (in comparison to the generic file); did I miss something with the modules ?

This pv ops is taking my hairs out, if somone has a clue ...

Comment: Great Help. In my case, for XCP and Ubuntu 11 I did this: menuentry "XCP release 1.6" --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os { insmod part_gpt insmod ext2 set root='(hd1,gpt1)' search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 90588eec-1d22-461e-9937-4d33994832af multiboot /boot/xen.gz mem=1024G module /boot/vmlinuz-2.6-xen root=/dev/sdb1 ro xencons=hvc console=hvc0 console=tty0 quiet vga=785 splash module /boot/initrd-2.6-xen.img
} Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change you root partition in the first module parameter (`module /vmlinuz-2.6.32.27 root=`). You have to change it to `/dev/sda5` (Becase in the current entry you have entered the boot partitions uuid).

You can get the uuid from `blkid /dev/sda5`